# Chinese Remainder Theorem: four square roots of 1 modulo N

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given an odd composite number $N$, where $N$ is not a prime power, I read the following in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Procedure):

> As a consequence of the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), the number $1$ has at
>   least four distinct square roots modulo $N$, two of them being $1$ and $-1$.

The square roots of $1$ and $-1$ are obvious to me. What I don't understand is why there are necessarily two others.

Can anyone prove how this result follows from the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: The correct statement is that $N$ should be the product of two (distinct) odd primes

Comment: @gammatester Sorry, there was a detail I missed: N is not a prime power (edited now)

Comment: Good. *now* you use CRT, to find something that’s like $1$ at one prime, $-1$ at another.

Comment: "The correct statement is that N should be the product of two (distinct) odd primes"  Actually  "N is the product of two relatively prime odd numbers other than one".  They don't need to be prime.  Just odd, and relatively prime to each other.

Comment: And N doesn't need to be odd.  It just needs to be the product of two relatively prime numbers larger than $2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows very simply from the observation that if you have two coprime moduli, $p$ and $q$, then 
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv a \bmod p \\
x\equiv a \bmod q \\
\end{cases}
\qquad \implies x\equiv a \bmod pq
$$
as a special case of the CRT. (I would like to write the paired equivalence as $x\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (a,a)$)

Then apply this here with 
$$\begin{cases}
x^2\equiv 1 \bmod p \\
x^2\equiv 1 \bmod q \\
\end{cases}
\qquad \implies x^2\equiv 1 \bmod pq
$$
... or $x^2\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (1,1)\implies x^2= 1 \bmod pq$

Then with $p,q>2$ (so that ${-}1{\not\equiv}1$), we can see that $x^2\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (1,1)$ will hold for each of $x\underset{(p,q)}\equiv \{(1,1),$ $(1,-1),(-1,1),$ $(-1,-1)\}$. These will each produce different roots of $1\bmod pq$ with the final values of $x\bmod pq$ determined through the CRT

---

As an example of how this works out, $21\underset{(5,11)}\equiv (1,-1)$ so $21^2\underset{(5,11)}\equiv (1,1)$ and thus $21^2\equiv 1 \bmod 55$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation in your last sentence. How is $x$ congruent to an ordered pair (or a set of them)?

Comment: It's not clear to me that introducing the 'special case' of the CRT really does much here when you need the theorem's full power (or at least most of the it) to then turn e.g. $(-1, 1)$ into a single residue class mod $pq$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki To find the roots, I agree, but I'm just aiming to demonstrate their existence.

Comment: I don't understand how the implication that $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod pq$ works for, say, $(1,-1)$, since you're picking different $x's$. I'm probably misinterpreting your meaning, because I don't see how the argument implies the existence of square roots.

Comment: @Jean-JacqduPlessis Right, if $x\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (1,-1)$ then $x^2\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (1,1)$ so $x^2\equiv 1 \bmod pq$. But $x\underset{(p,q)}\equiv (1,-1)$ also means that $x\not\equiv 1$  and $x\not\equiv -1\bmod pq$

Comment: Ahh, of course, $x$ is squared. But my final dilemma is why $x \equiv_{(p,q)} (1,-1)$ implies $x \not\equiv 1\ \mathrm{mod}\ pq$. I get a contradiction, since $x \equiv_{(p,q)} (1,-1)$ implies specifically $x \equiv 1\ \mathrm{mod}\ p$, so $(x-1)$ divides $p$, which divides $pq$, so $x \equiv 1\ \mathrm{mod}\ pq$. Contradiction?

Comment: Since $x\equiv -1 \bmod q$, clearly  $x\not \equiv 1 \bmod pq$. And since $x\equiv 1 \bmod p$, clearly  $x\not \equiv -1 \bmod pq$ (and I should point out the restriction that $p,q>2$)

Comment: I am convinced! Thank you very much @Joffan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80399/discussion-between-jean-jacq-du-plessis-and-joffan).

Answer (score 5):

If $N$ is divisible by two distinct odd primes (say $p, q$), besides $1, -1$, you can also choose $i$ such that $i \equiv 1 \mod p^{\nu_p(N)}, i \equiv -1 \mod q^{\nu_q(N)}, i \equiv 0 \mod \frac{n}{p^{\nu_p(N)}q^{\nu_q(N)}}$ and $j$ such that $j i \equiv -1 \mod p^{\nu_p(N)}, i \equiv 1 \mod q^{\nu_q(N)}, i \equiv 0 \mod \frac{n}{p^{\nu_p(n)}q^{\nu_q(N)}}$.

In general if $N$ is divisible by atleast $m$ odd primes, then there are **exactly** $2^m$ numbers whose square is congruent to $1$ modulo $N$.

Here $\nu_p(m)$ denotes the highest power of $p$ dividing $m$ (for example, $\nu_3(27) = 3$, $\nu_3(18) = 2$, $\nu_3(10) = 0$)

Comment: Your line with "at least" and "exactly" seems contradictory to me. Maybe "at least" should change?

Also, I'm not sure where you're going with $ji \equiv -1 \mod p^{v_p(N)}$. Would you mind explaining what that implies?

Answer (score 3):

If $f:\mathbb Z_N \to 
    \mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}} \times Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}} 
    \times \cdots \times Z_{p_n^{\alpha_n}}$

where $N = p_1^{\alpha_1} \times p_1^{\alpha_1} \times \cdots \times p_n^{\alpha_n}$

is a group isomorphism (via the CRT), then every number of the form

$$f^{-1}(\pm 1, \pm 1, \dots, \pm 1)$$

is a square root of $1$ in $\mathbb Z_N$.

### added 9/3/2022

Viewed from the other direction.

If $f: \mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}} \times Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}} 
    \times \cdots \times Z_{p_n^{\alpha_n}} \to \mathbb Z_N$

is a group isomorphism (via the CRT), then every number of the form

$$f(\pm 1, \pm 1, \dots, \pm 1)$$

is a square root of $1$ in $\mathbb Z_N$.

For example, the map $f:Z_3 \times Z_5 \times Z_7 \to Z_{105}$ defined by
$f(x,y,z) = 70x + 21y + 15z \pmod{105}$ is a group isomorphism. We get
$$f( 1, 1, 1) \equiv   1 \pmod{105}$$
$$f( 1, 1,-1) \equiv  76 \pmod{105}$$
$$f( 1,-1, 1) \equiv  64 \pmod{105}$$
$$f( 1,-1,-1) \equiv  34 \pmod{105}$$
$$f(-1, 1, 1) \equiv  71 \pmod{105}$$
$$f(-1, 1,-1) \equiv  41 \pmod{105}$$
$$f(-1,-1, 1) \equiv  29 \pmod{105}$$
$$f(-1,-1,-1) \equiv 104 \pmod{105}$$

and $       1^2 \equiv 76^2 \equiv 64^2 \equiv  34^2 
    \equiv 71^2 \equiv 41^2 \equiv 29^2 \equiv 104^2 \pmod {105}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $N = mn$ with $mn$ relatively prime and both odd.

Then among the equivalence classes $\mod N$:

by CRT for each of the following systems of equation there is exactly one solution:

- $x \equiv 1 \mod m$ and $x\equiv 1 \mod m$.  (In this case $x \equiv
     1 \mod mn$).
- $y \equiv 1 \mod m$ and $y \equiv -1 \mod m$.
- $w \equiv -1 \mod m$ and $w\equiv 1\mod m$
- $u \equiv -1\mod m$ and $w\equiv -1 \mod m$.(this is $u \equiv -1
     \mod mn$).

These are four distinct values $\mod mn$.

Now all four of these values have the properties that:

- $x^2 \equiv y^2 \equiv z^2 \equiv u^2 \equiv 1 \mod m$ and $x^2 \equiv y^2 \equiv z^2 \equiv u^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$.

By CRT there is exactly one solution $\mod mn$ to *that*:

$x^2 \equiv y^2\equiv z^2 \equiv u^2 \equiv 1 \mod mn$.